# How to show a html string n uilabel in xcode

Tags: xcode

When I parse a URL, I'm getting the result in HTML format, so how to load that HTML string in  `UILabel`  or `UITextView`?

Comment: better use UIWebView for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not applicable for iOS as the AppKit.framework required is only for MacOS development.

Best solution to this problem so far seems to be the [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) class available on GitHub.